# Balanced payments API doubts

Tags: python, python-2.7, payment-gateway, balanced-payments

I'm trying to integrate balanced payments API into my work. I've looked at Docs and other concerned forums also but didn't get clear my doubts.
I understand the flow of this though, but due to some method names i'm getting confused.
e.g. customer.

https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.0/overview/getting-started/#charge-a-credit-card

What have I tried till now:(in Python)

I've created a dummy/Test bank and it's working fine.
`bank_account = balanced.BankAccount(...)`      but I dont know how much could I debit from this or first do I have to credit into.

after this I created a card and then I created a customer `customer = balanced.Customer().save()`

and then associated the card with the customer `customer.add_card('/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP52IlCmywk6hGbgS75QSlN/cards/CC3AiMy0KEP1PhwnffMk32RF')`

but how is this statement working?
`customer.add_bank_account('/v1/bank_accounts/BA24Zc2jo1moflunJDxKrCrB')`

I'm slightly confused with this `customer` word.

Could somebody please explain this from beginning in simple steps.

Answer (score 3):

[Customers](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.0/api/customers/#creating-a-customer) are objects that represent businesses or people within your marketplace (i.e. buyers and sellers). In this revision of the API, funding instruments (e.g. credit cards, bank accounts) must be associated to a specific customer object before you can initiate any transactions.

The method you listed:

```
customer.add_bank_account('/v1/bank_accounts/BA24Zc2jo1moflunJDxKrCrB')
```

Is associating the bank account to the customer object that you created.

You specify the amount for a [debit](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.0/api/debits/#create-a-new-debit) (charge) or [credit](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.0/api/credits/#credit-an-existing-bank-account) (payout). The limit depends on a number of factors (e.g. credit limit, available funds, [transaction limits](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.0/overview/processing/#transaction-limits))